# Can't install vmware tools on Windows 2016 standard

Tags: vmware-fusion, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install VMWare Tools on Windows 2016 standard, but got the following result, any ideas?

I'm using VMWare Fusion 10.0.1

[image]

Comment: Install the Microsoft Runtime you don’t have a required package installed.  Check Vmware documentation for what is required

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator just removed

Comment: @Ramhound Which document should I look at? I mean, I need to know which VC runtime package to install

Comment: Appears like VC++ 2005 SP1 based on my research with regards to VMware Tools and “Microsoft runtime”.  If you run the installer exe with a /?you can generate a log, that allows you to see the temporary folder that is created, allowing you to manually copy the required runtime installer and running it yourself.  [Seems simple to solve.](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/278866?start=15&tstart=0)